# MVC 6 Routing, SPA fallback + 404 Error Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc, angular2-routing

With [**RC1**](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap#schedule) of **ASP.NET Core 1.0's MVC 6** you can map routes from within your `Startup.Configure` function when invoking `app.UseMvc`. I have mapped a "spa-fallback" route that will ensure that the `HomeController` and `Index` view are the defaults like so:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                      IHostingEnvironment env, 
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // ... omitted for brevity
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Home/Error/{0}");

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        routes.MapRoute("spa-fallback", "{*anything}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        routes.MapWebApiRoute("defaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

I desire the fallback so that my **Angular2** app's routes will not result in an HTTP Status Code of **404, Not Found**. But I also need to correctly handle when a user does inadvertently attempt to navigate to a page view that doesn't exist. You might notice that I have also called `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Home/Error/{0}");`.

The call to redirect to my error page with the status code and the "spa-fallback" route seem mutually exclusive -- meaning it appears that I can only have one or the other *(but sadly not both)*. Does anyone know how I could manage to have the best of both worlds?

Comment: Currently the new package can be found in "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices": "1.0.0-beta-000005".

Comment: @SamanAhmadi, I saw that... thank you

Comment: @DavidPine would you consider changing the accepted answer?  Trying to build my street cred ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It took me some time to figure out how to do this without serving my index using MVC and to still receive 404s for missing files. Here's my http pipeline:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(                
            routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "api",
                    template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

                // ## commented out since I don't want to use MVC to serve my index.    
                // routes.MapRoute(
                //     name:"spa-fallback", 
                //     template: "{*anything}", 
                //     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });

        // ## this serves my index.html from the wwwroot folder when 
        // ## a route not containing a file extension is not handled by MVC.  
        // ## If the route contains a ".", a 404 will be returned instead.
        app.MapWhen(context => context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
                               !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value),
                    branch => {
                           branch.Use((context, next) => {
                               context.Request.Path = new PathString("/index.html");
                               Console.WriteLine("Path changed to:" + context.Request.Path.Value);
                               return next();});

                    branch.UseStaticFiles();
        });            
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, I should have updated my question or deleted it earlier -- since I had already figured it out after the fact.

Comment: This solution is nice since it doesn't require having MVC.  I am currently using ASP.NET as a static file server (no MVC), but I do want to be able to reroute non asset paths to `index.html`.

Comment: Nice answer


I recommend using slightly better code for the When predicate:

`context => context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value)`

Comment: thanks! I'll update the answer to include this improvement.

Comment: In my case, I am not using any MVC routes - other than static files, all logical paths should route to index.html. So, I first removed the UseMvc statement. And then, I had to remove the `context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&` part as I was getting a 200 for all requests otherwise.

Comment: I'm using Mvc but still StatusCode 404 check isn't working. I think its probably cause I'm getting 404 on the page but 200 on favicon cause of Chrome.

Comment: I've the same problem in mvc 5. Does anyone have an idea how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I came up with two possible workarounds/solutions.

**ASP.NET Core 1.0, RC1**

With **Angular2** specifically, we can simply swap out the `LocationStrategy`. For example in my `wwwroot/app/boot.ts` I have the following:

```
import {provide} from "angular2/core";
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";

import {AppComponent} from "./app.component"

bootstrap(AppComponent,
    [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
    ]);
```

Note that I am utilizing the `provide` function to override the standard `LocationStrategy` with the `HashLocationStrategy`. This adds the `#` in the URL and prevents MVC from incorrectly throwing **404's**, but also correctly handles responding with **404's** when the user manually types in a *URL* that doesn't exist.

**ASP.NET Core 1.0, RC2**

Simply use [`Microsoft.AspNet.NodeServices`](https://github.com/aspnet/NodeServices#using-angularservicesreactservices-in-your-own-projects). Within this library there are both `AngularServices` and `ReactServices` which allow for the mapping of SPA routes specifically, via the [`MapSpaFallbackRoute`](https://github.com/aspnet/NodeServices/blob/74cac774f8800f59da9aaf98950b7da9e2297d72/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SpaServices/Routing/SpaRouteExtensions.cs) function. I state that we need to wait for **RC2** with the understanding that the current implementations are not fully functioning as desired.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this, Im going to check it out. On the angular side, I didn't want to use hash location strategy since it isn't required with html5 browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostingEnvironment env,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Home/Error/{0}");

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        routes.MapWebApiRoute("defaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
    });

    app.Run(async context =>
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    });
}
```

app.Run() will catch all requests that doesn't match any of the routes defined earlier. This way you can get your custom spa fallback and use app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects() at the same time.